# Android build succeeding with Xamarin Studio (OSX) but failing with XBuild

Tags: android, xamarin, xbuild

Title says it all really. I have a project that builds in Xamarin Studio on OSX but fails when I try and use xbuild to build it from the command line. I'm running

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/xbuild /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release ../foo/foo.sln
```

to build the app and I'm getting errors like:

```
obj/Release/android/src/mono/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomStatusUpdateListenerImplementor.java(51,97): error :  error: package com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime does not exist
private native void n_onDisconnectedFromRoom (com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.Room p0);
```

and

```
obj/Release/android/src/mono/android/support/v7/internal/widget/ActivityChooserModel_OnChooseActivityListenerImplementor.java(8,58):  javacerror :  error: package android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActivityChooserModel does not exist
    android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActivityChooserModel.OnChooseActivityListener
```

I'm updated Xamarin to the latest bits (5.10.1)

Comment: Were you able to get a fix for this?

Comment: From [this page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/jenkins_walkthrough/) it seems that you should use the target "PackageForAndroid" instead, but [this page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/) does not list that target. I think you should contact Xamarin support instead of wasting your time.